# How to custom post type in wordpress different style

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to customize the posts for each category to be different. but I can't do it, can you please take a look at me, where is my mistake?

For example, I have 2 categories.

1 window
2 android

I want the windows category to call the content-windows-details.php file.

android content-app-details.php

But now the category Windows will call the app-details.php file.  i need to windown call  windows-details.php

Code single.php

```html
    <?php

    /**

     * The template for displaying all single posts

     *

     * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#single-post

     *

     * 

     */



    get_header();

    $p_id = get_the_ID();       
    $terms = get_the_terms( $p_id, 'category' ); 
    $is_tip = false;
    $cat_id = 0;
    foreach($terms as $term) { 
        if( !is_app_cat($term->term_id)){
            $is_tip = true;
            $cat_id = $term->term_id;
            break;
        }
        else{
            if($term->parent != 0){
                $cat_id = $term->term_id;
            }
        }
    } 
    if($is_tip){
        $is_topten = false;
        foreach($terms as $term) { 
            if($term->slug == 'windows'){
                $is_topten = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if($is_topten){
            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'windows-details' ); 
        }
        else{
            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'single' );
            
        }
    }
    else{
        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'app-details' );
    }



    ?>


    <?php

    get_footer();
```

Answer (score 0):

WordPress has built-in support for this kind of thing (I believe you are using WordPress). You just need to rename your files.

Instead of content-windoes-details.php, use **category-windows.php**

Same thing for Android; it's **category-android.php**

That way, the correct file will be used when displaying posts from each category.

The Codex page about this is here: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#examples

Comment: Yes i have 

category-windows.php   > post file   content-windows-details.php 
category-android.php    > post file    content-app-details.php 

but now working when i open post in  windows it call file content-app-details.php

Comment: Then I wonder if maybe your $is_tip is returning false at some point (maybe finding default or "uncategorized" term, even after break?) and so it's always hitting the final "else" in your loop. But I don't know what your is_app_cat() function is doing, so it might be an issue there.